# Minimizing the write-outage time of the database deployed on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, raid

Say we have a relational database on EC2 instance. It has a set of EBS volumes in RAID mode. We perform a procedure of backing-up this instance. How to minimize the time during which we cannot write to the database while this backup is performed?

Comment: You probably need to supply the answers so we can try to figure out what the person creating the quiz was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key concern is not taking the database down then you can take snapshots. If you take the snapshots while the instance is quiesced the snapshots will be consistent, but you can shut the instance down for 10 seconds you can be 100% sure of consistent snapshots. The key here is once a snapshot is started you can continue to modify the volume but the snapshot will be taken as of the time you requested the snapshot. You can then mount the snapshots to a new instance and take a backup. That's the hard way, but probably the least downtime, and maybe it can be automated.

You could also simply export the database using the vendor tools to another volume or S3, which typically does not interrupt database use.

There are no doubt other ways, probably some better, which others will answer. The question will probably be closed sooner or later as SF is for real world business problems rather than helping with exams.

Comment: I just want to clarify out of curiosity: why is "once a snapshot is started you can continue to modify the volume"? What the technical nuance behind the scene?

Comment: We don't know what the behind the scene technology is, we just know that AWS says once you start a snapshot it's taken as at the time the snapshot is started, even if the volume is modified while the snapshot is being taken. I guess it's something like volume shadow copy